# Why does my bash script move beyond "docker run" even tho docker is still running?

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying with a bash script to run a docker container then print a message.  However the finished message is executed whilst the container is still running - I can exec into it and see PID 1 and multiple other processes.

How can I force the docker run command to complete first?

```
docker run --name registr \
         -v ~/v1:/v1 \
         -v ~/logging.yaml:/root/logging.yaml \
         -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
         -v ~/luigi.cfg:/root/luigi.cfg \
         -v ~/params:/root/params \
         -p 8082:8082 \
         simonm3/registr
echo "docker finished"

The docker image has CMD ["python", "/root/worker/start.py"]
```

Comment: Do you want the container to be running or stopped after the command execution? Could you please explain a bit more, to me it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Stopped. I want the container to execute and exit THEN the message to be displayed. A slightly different container does exactly that. I am unclear why this one moves on to the echo before the container exits.

Comment: Perhaps the docker command runs immediately in background returning control the the shell. Check if there's an option to prevent that.

Comment: I can add a -t which makes it block. However when I run other containers the run command blocks without this. I am not sure what is different about this one.